# How to use meta tags in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm trying to use vue-meta in a VueJs 3 project, but when I configure it, the screen is all white.

I'm using the alpha.10 version as reported in the documentation.

Install NPM:

`npm install --save vue-meta@^3.0.0-alpha.10`

```html
<script>
import { useMeta } from 'vue-meta'
export default {
  name: 'HomeView',
  setup() {
    useMeta({
      title: 'Site name - Page Name',
      htmlAttrs: {
        lang: 'pt-br',
      }
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

One of my concerns is with the SEO of the project, so it's not simply changing the post-render tags. Some things need to be SSR.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/vueuse/head

```
useHead({
    title: 'Site name - Page Name',
    htmlAttrs: {
        lang: 'pt-br',
    }
})
```